# Gnuplot: How to plot only last occurance of block with repeating y-values

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way without using external programs to avoid plotting multiple y-values at x-positions in Gnuplot?

I've studied Gnuplot 5.* documentation and found only some not enough close approaches: for example `smooth unique` plots *average* of all y-values, `smooth frequency` plots *sum* of all y-values. I want to take only the last value - alike y-values were "overwriting".

I don't want to preprocess the data because I need to keep records in their data blocks, as I need to plot vertical line after each block.

Ideal solution would be block-oriented, i.e. avoid whole duplicated blocks, but I would be also grateful for y-oriented solution that plots unique y-values with the last occurance, regardless of the blocks.

Here's my recent code (the important parts):

```
stats ifname using 1 nooutput
columns = STATS_columns
blocks = STATS_blocks

ymax = -1e30
do for [i=2:columns] {
    stats ifname using i nooutput
    ymax = (ymax > valid(STATS_max)) ? ymax : STATS_max
}

plot for [j=2:columns] ifname using 1:j, \
  "" using 1:(column(0) == 1 ? ymax : NaN) axes x1y2 with impulse notitle lc black lw 0.75 dashtype 2
```

Data example:

```
t sqr sqrt y 
4.000000    16.000000 2.000000 8.491226 
4.010000    16.080100 2.002498 8.576564 
4.055000    16.443025 2.013703 8.971325 
4.257500    18.126306 2.063371 10.985030 
4.510790    20.347226 2.123862 14.151540 
4.764080    22.696458 2.182677 18.230817 
5.000000    25.000000 2.236068 23.081549 


t sqr sqrt y 
5.000000    25.000000 2.236068 23.081549 
5.010000    25.100100 2.238303 23.313522 
5.055000    25.553025 2.248333 24.386594 
5.257500    27.641306 2.292924 29.860411 
5.508013    30.338210 2.346916 38.361213 
5.758527    33.160628 2.399693 49.282063 
6.000000    36.000000 2.449490 62.742164 


t sqr sqrt y 
5.000000    25.000000 2.236068 23.081549 
5.010000    25.100100 2.238303 23.083547 
5.055000    25.553025 2.248333 23.092489 
5.257500    27.641306 2.292924 23.131767 
6.000000    36.000000 2.449490 23.263871 


t sqr sqrt y 
6.000000    36.000000 2.449490 23.263871 
6.010000    36.120100 2.451530 23.497677 
6.055000    36.663025 2.460691 24.579225 
6.257500    39.156306 2.501500 30.096280 
6.508000    42.354068 2.551079 38.663729 
6.758501    45.677331 2.599712 49.670058 
7.000000    49.000000 2.645752 63.237766
```

What I want to achieve is to completely ignore the second block. Here's the result so far:
[image]

Note that this example where I want `y` to stay under `sqr` is only special case, all functions can be independent.

EDIT: I added some minor changes to the end of ewcz's script (columnhead):

```
set y2range [0:ymax]

plot for [j=2:columns] for [b=0:blocks-1] ifname index b \
  using 1:(ignore[b+1] ? NaN : column(j)) lt (j-1) \
  title b==0 ? columnhead(j) : "", \
for [b=0:blocks-1] "" index b \
  using 1:(ignore[b+1] ? NaN : column(0) == 1 ? ymax : NaN) \
  axes x1y2 with impulse notitle \
  lc black lw 0.5 dashtype 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvised workaround which ignores certain blocks based on a custom criterion could be as follows (for details, see comments in the code):

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced rounded
set output 'fig.png'

ifname = 'data.dat'

stats ifname using 1 nooutput
columns = STATS_columns
blocks = STATS_blocks

array signatures[blocks]
do for [j=0:blocks-1] {
  stats ifname index j:j using 1 nooutput

  #For each block, generate an identifier based on which we will decide if two
  #blocks are "duplicit" or not. In this particular case, consider the minimum
  #and maximum to 3 decimal digits. Due to the character of the technique used
  #below, this identifier should be a valid Gnuplot variable name.
  signatures[j+1] = sprintf("block_%d_%d", STATS_min*1000, STATS_max*1000)
}

#this array marks if a block should be ignored or not.
array ignore[blocks]

#Process blocks in reverse order and for each of them, check if the given
#signature has been already seen or not. If yes, it means that there is
#a more recent equivalent block in the data and the current block should
#be thus ignored. In order to check if a signature has been already seen,
#we set a corresponding variable and then test its existence via exists().
do for [j=blocks-1:0:-1] {
  signature = signatures[j+1]
  eval sprintf("ignore[%d] = exists(\"%s\");%s = 1;", j+1, signature, signature);
}

ymax = -1e30
do for [i=2:columns] {
    stats ifname using i nooutput
    ymax = (ymax > valid(STATS_max)) ? ymax : STATS_max
}

plot for [j=2:columns] for [b=0:blocks-1] ifname index b:b using 1:(ignore[b+1]?NaN:column(j)) w l lt (j-1) t b==0?sprintf('column %d', j):'', \
  "" using 1:(column(0) == 1 ? ymax : NaN) axes x1y2 with impulse notitle lc black lw 0.75 dashtype 2
```

this produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I was wondering if there are array structures since I did not found them in the manual.
I added some minor changes into the main thread.

Comment: @TomášKolárik my pleasure! The `array` construct is available since Gnuplot 5.1, I believe...